# Как изменить картинку на imageButton из кода?

Tags: android

Я использую один адаптер для нескольких фрагментов, и мне надо, чтобы `imageButton` в одном фрагменте была с одной картинкой, а в другом фрагменте с другой. Как это сделать?

Код, где я создаю `holder`:

```
    public TaskViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        int LayoutIdForListItem = 0;
        ImageButton imageButton;

        switch (viewType){
            case TYPE_IS_COMMENT_IS_SUBTASKS:
                LayoutIdForListItem = R.layout.is_comment_is_subtasks;
                break;
            case TYPE_IS_COMMENT_ISNT_SUBTASKS:
                LayoutIdForListItem = R.layout.is_comment_isnt_subtasks;
                break;
            case TYPE_ISNT_COMMENT_ISNT_SUBTASKS:
                LayoutIdForListItem = R.layout.isnt_comment_isnt_subtasks;
                break;
            case TYPE_ISNT_COMMENT_IS_SUBTASKS:
                LayoutIdForListItem = R.layout.isnt_comment_is_subtasks;
                break;
            case TYPE_ISNT_CHECKBOX_IS_COMMENT_ISNT_SUBTASKS:
                LayoutIdForListItem = R.layout.isnt_checkbox_is_comment_isnt_subtasks;
                break;
            case TYPE_ISNT_CHECKBOX_IS_COMMENT_IS_SUBTASKS:
                LayoutIdForListItem = R.layout.isnt_checkbox_is_comment_is_subtasks;
                break;
            case TYPE_ISNT_CHECKBOX_ISNT_COMMENT_IS_SUBTASKS:
                LayoutIdForListItem = R.layout.isnt_checkbox_isnt_comment_is_subtasks;
                break;
            case TYPE_ISNT_CHECKBOX_ISNT_COMMENT_ISNT_SUBTASKS:
                LayoutIdForListItem = R.layout.isnt_checkbox_isnt_comment_isnt_subtasks;
                break;
        }

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(LayoutIdForListItem, parent, false);

        return new TaskViewHolder(view, viewType);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Программно картинку можно поменять таким способом:

```
Drawable tempImage = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image);
tempButton.setImageDrawable(tempImage);
```

либо так:

```
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.newimage);
```